# Php session unable to process input

Tags: php, session

I have this code that requires the user to type in a number and that number of lessons will be created.

```
<form action="k1levelselect.php" method="post"> How many lessons do you want to create?
<input type="text" name="number" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['views']=$number;
?>
```

Then it will bring me to the next page and prints out the number of 'Lessons' the user wants.

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    $noOfLesson = $_SESSION['views'];
        for($i = 1; $i <= $noOfLesson; $i++) {
        echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
    echo "<div>
        <a href=\"k1levelX.php?lesson=".$i."\"><span>Lesson ".$i."</span></a>           
    </div>
    <br>";
        }
        ?>
```

The problem is in the first code, i am not able to bring the input 'number' over to the session using $_SESSION['views']=$number;
However, it works when i hardcode a number like eg. $_SESSION['views']=4;

Comment: Uhh.  Where is `$number` defined?

Comment: ...it isn't defined; that's just it.

Comment: I know, was a blatant hint...

Comment: hehe I know. I was about to `$_POST` a comment to that effect. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Foreword:*** (edit)
I noticed you've asked a few questions since first joining Stack but have not accepted any.

If there is a reason as to why you haven't accepted any, probably because none of the answers given solved an issue, do inform the person or persons to elaborate on their answer.

- Please read the following article: [**How does accepting an answer work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

---

***Answer:***

Here, this is what you need to do, in regards to your comment about it "not working": (plus, you weren't assigning a variable in regards to your POST form element). This has already been explained.

**Your (new) form:** - Make sure there is nothing above this (no space, cookie, HTML, nothing), because it will cause/throw a "`Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at...`" error; **if** [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is ON by default.

```
<?php

session_start();

// check if session is set, which will echo the last entered number
if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
echo $_SESSION['views'];
}

?>

<form action="k1levelselect.php" method="post">
How many lessons do you want to create?
<input type="text" name="number" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Copy this into your k1levelselect.php file:**  - Make sure there is nothing above this (no space, cookie, HTML, nothing), because it will cause/throw a "`Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at...`" error; **if** [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is ON by default.

```
<?php 

session_start();
$number = $_POST['number']; // assign variable from POST
$_SESSION['views']=$number; // assign session to variable

    $noOfLesson = $_SESSION['views'];
        for($i = 1; $i <= $noOfLesson; $i++) {
        echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
    echo "<div>
        <a href=\"k1levelX.php?lesson=".$i."\"><span>Lesson ".$i."</span></a>           
    </div>
    <br>";
        }
?>
```

---

**If** [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is not ON by default, add the following below your opening `<?php` tags:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will show you any errors; if any.

Answer (score 4):

You never assigned any value to `$number` which must first come from your named form element `number`. Assign a variable to the POST variable from your named form element, then use the session name and assign it to the `$number` variable.

```
session_start();
$number = $_POST['number'];
$_SESSION['views']=$number;
```

Comment: Oh come come now, you can add an explanation. ;)

Comment: More explanation please :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver I thought I'd put in my 2 cents in an edit ;) I hope Meda didn't mind :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @fred, from now on im going to make my answers more verbose, yours are always very detailed!

Comment: @Fred-ii- is the guy to check for answers, Telling you he's a nutter with them! ;-P

Comment: @Darren I try. I like to be sure of my shot when posting an actual "answer". Plus, I don't need to try hard to be a "nutter"; sometimes I feel like a nut, and sometimes I don't ;) most of the times; yes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha well said. I followed your steps as I'd personally like to "learn" why the issue is, instead of just receiving code that fixes it (*if I asked the question*). It also allows you to assert why and how your code works :D

Comment: @Darren Exactly Darren. The points were fun at first, yet the actual "better feeling" (now), is knowing that the way it was explained, will hopefully have created a better coder. Remember, *"success breeds success."* ;)

Comment: lol @Darren this is also a very important skills for documentation. code without explanation is pretty much useless

Comment: I tried doing that before already but it didn't work. An error prints out saying 'Undefined index: number'

Comment: @meda Exactly right :) and you can take it as a challenge, I love the complex questions, yet there aren't many being posted anymore :(

Comment: @user3583643 This code needs to be in `k1levelselect.php` and you should check if it is set `if($_POST(['number']){$_SESSION['views']=$number;}`

Comment: @Darren yes not as many as the bad duplicated, I think also php is fairly simple.

Comment: @user3583643 Remove all your PHP from inside the form. Then, add what Meda gave you for the answer inside the other file `k1levelselect.php`; it will work.